# How can I mix Bootstrap's grid with another grid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating an HTML page based on a spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has its own colors and data-specifications, of course, but it also has its own column widths.

I've been using Bootstrap for my app, up to this point. Bootstrap, of course, is highly opinionated about column and row dimensions. One could argue that these opinions are its raison d'être.

The question then is this: Can I say to Bootstrap "go not ye within this area" and make my own grid? Or does Bootstrap insist on arranging the whole body, and I'll therefore need to abandon it for this page?

CLARIFICATION: I've included an example: I'm getting data from a server that's interpreting a spreadsheet and need to draw a representation of that spreadsheet based on the column widths and row heights that are sent from the server. So I don't think Bootstrap can help me here, and the question is: Will it get out of the way.

In other words, given a variety of spreadsheets like the attached (where I don't know in advance the layout and, in fact, have no control over the layout), is there a way to make Bootstrap leave that particular area alone.[image: Sample] Note how high row 1 is and how narrow H and I are, etc.

Comment: Can you specify your question a little bit? "go not ye within this area" is hardly understandable. What own grid? What own grid, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close all of your containers, rows, and columns before your custom grid. Then after your custom grid, create new containers, rows, and columns.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="custom">
 <!--Your custom code-->
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind, you can nest the Bootstrap grid as well as change the amount of columns.

Comment: sensible approach... likely what I would do but also with the aid of a `reset.css` that affects only my `.custom` container

Comment: I'm gonna accept this because it seems plausible. I haven't actually checked because I need to clean up the code in some other ways. I will add another comment after this when I have, just for people who come after me.